# issue with Inserting with last inserted id

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

**What I have:** A database with 2 tables: Reactions and ReactionImages.
An user can post a reaction with some images. So the table Reactions has an auto increment id. And the table ReactionImages has a column called: Reaction_id. So thru that way they are connected. See the code below how I upload the reaction + images:

```
 if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){
            unset($q1);
            $q1['reactie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['editor1']);
            $q1['topic_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicid']);
            $q1['klant_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['klantid']);
            $q1['ledenpagina_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['ledenpaginaid']);
            $q1['onderreactie_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['onderreactieID']);
            $app->insert_query('reacties', $q1, 'id');

            if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'])){

                foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
                    $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
                    $file_name = $app->makeurlshop($file_name); 
                    $file_name = $app->check_string($file_name);
                    $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];

                    if(($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] == 1) or ($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] == 2)){
                        echo  '<script>alert("<div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Mislukt</h4>
                            Je foto is te groot, verklein de foto eerst in bijvoorbeeld paint of photoshop.
                          </div>");</script>';
                    }

                    $gelukt = $app->fotoupload($file_tmp, $file_name, 'assets/images/reactiefotos', 800);

                    if($gelukt == 'ok'){
                        unset($q1);
                        $q1['reactie_id'] = $database->lastInsertId();
                        $q1['foto'] = $file_name;
                        $app->insert_query2('fotoreactie', $q1);

                     } else {
                        echo '<script>alert("'.$gelukt.'");</script>';
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

**My problem is:** When I upload a reaction with 2 or more images. The first image get's the correct reaction_id. But the second image get's the id from the image that has been uploaded before this one. I know why it happens because I use `$database->lastInsertId();` But how do I make it work to upload for example 2 images and to get both images to get the same reaction_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the reaction id into a variable

`$app->insert_query('reacties', $q1, 'id');
$reactie_id = $database->lastInsertId();`

And then inside the loop use it.

`$q1['reactie_id'] = $reactie_id;`

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a basic solution for the time being, before the `foreach` make a variable like `$photoUploaded = false;` then when you get the last insert ID , set it to true and then have a if statement beforehand checking if it is true or not, if it is true use the last insert ID... Like so:

```
$photoUpload = false;
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
    $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
    $file_name = $app->makeurlshop($file_name); 
    $file_name = $app->check_string($file_name);
    $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];

    if(($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] == 1) or ($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] == 2)){
        echo  '<script>alert("<div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Mislukt</h4>
                     Je foto is te groot, verklein de foto eerst in bijvoorbeeld paint of photoshop.
    </div>");</script>';
    }

    $gelukt = $app->fotoupload($file_tmp, $file_name, 'assets/images/reactiefotos', 800);

    if($gelukt == 'ok'){
        unset($q1);
        if($photoUpload){
            $q1['foto'] = $file_name;
            $app->insert_query2('fotoreactie', $q1);
        }
        else{
            $q1['reactie_id'] = $database->lastInsertId();
            $q1['foto'] = $file_name;
            $app->insert_query2('fotoreactie', $q1);
            $photoUpload = true;
        }

    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$gelukt.'");</script>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting last insert id immediately after insert query and save it in a variable for later use.